# Is it possible to have multiple Rmd file templates for the blogdown “new post” addin?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I'd like to be able to select among two (or more) archetypes when using the "new post" addin in blogdown. The screenshots at https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/pull/263 suggest that, if I add a "post.md" file to the archetypes directory in my theme then it will be available in the Archetype dropdown menu. However, I've added such a file, and even after restarting R I don't get anything other than "default" as an option.

Looking at new_post.R, it seems that the key phrase is

`choices = unique(c('default', xfun::sans_ext(dir('archetypes', '\\.md$'))`

but I don't see anywhere that the path to the theme is being defined, suggesting that the latter part doesn't find a valid directory and so isn't actually generating a list of files.

Indeed, if I change 'default' to 'foo' in the above line, then my only option in the Archetype menu is foo.

I should note that edits I make to defaults.md in my archetypes directory *do* get applied by new_post, so hugo is finding the directory; it is just the shiny app that appears not to find it.

I originally found this using the current release version (0.9); I get the same result using v. 9.2 from GitHub.

It may well be that I'm missing something fundamental (e.g., an options setting somewhere), and if so I apologize :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `.md` file to the `archetypes` directory of your website *root directory*, instead of the theme directory.

Comment: Thanks! My site root directory did not already have an `archetypes` directory (and hence when I went looking for `archetypes`, the only place I found it was in the theme), so I had to create one. Putting the `.md` files there indeed solved the problem. I also note that `default.md` in the site `archetypes` overrides the one in the theme.

Comment: Hi @YihuiXie. I've been using Hugo for a while now and the ability that provides blogdown to write `.Rmd` files is really great but when it comes to archetypes handle I really don't get it. I mean, the [official documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/archetypes/) about archetypes stablish a lookup order for the archerype declaration as long as the theme name is set in the `config.toml` file so there's no need to place the files in the root directory. Is there a way to go with this default behaviour or to copy, by default, the folder from the themes directory to the root directory?

Comment: @DavidDaza I just made a few changes in the dev version of **blogdown**. Please test it with `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')`. This version will respect Hugo's lookup order for archetypes, and will also list the available archetypes in the theme. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, i'ts working for me now as expected. Thank you!